# sending commands from excel file to a c# program

Tags: c#, excel

I have a program that reads Data from Excel and write data to Excel file. I need to send commands from the Excel file to the c# program (e.g. capture the F9 from the excel and get it on the c# program)

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel framework.

How can i do it?>

Comment: I don't know the exact answer.. but i'm sure you will need to use Win API as Interop doesn't have capability of capturing Keys.

Comment: It seems that F9 corresponds with "Calculate all worksheets in all open workbooks." Whatever you're doing, it might be done cleaner with a different method. You should provide details on what exactly you want to accomplish by detecting this command.

Answer (score 1):

the excel application interface also provides events to some excel functions, e.g.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application:

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Occurs after any worksheet is recalculated or after any changed data is plotted
    //     on a chart.
    event AppEvents_SheetCalculateEventHandler SheetCalculate;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to call native Win32 methods to add a message hook looking for a character message in the Excel window.

Answer (score 0):

oferyo,

Hello. You don't mention what sorts of volume of data you need to deal with? Or the type, either (questions like: does the stuff 'sent' to the destination Excel file includes graphs or just data?).

You don't mention which version of C# you are using but you could consider calling a web service from the VBA script embedded in or added to the originating Excel spreadsheet?

[MSDN article on calling WebServices from within VBA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140260%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

I can't recall how to plumb VBA code into specific events on the Excel spreadsheet (like the recalculate/press of F9) but I think that should be trivial.

If you are using C# 3.5 or later you can host a WCF service within the application ... but I would suggest describing the question better because it may be the VBA->WCF/WebService->Application solution might be seriously over-engineered?

Hope this helps you think about the options you have within VBA ...

regards,

Aidanapword